# Is it possible continues image changing in Base adapter in android?

Tags: android

This is my getView method in BaseAdapter. I want to change ImageView image every 5 seconds. So i write timer to change image. But this code not changing image. Please help me anyone.Thanks in Advance.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View layout = convertView;

    if (position == 0) {
        if (page1 == null) {
            layout = page1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page1, null);
            ImageView iv = (ImageView) page1.findViewById(R.id.page1_cover_img);


            Timer t = new Timer();
            t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    try {
                        if (i == 0) {
                            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                        } else if (i == 1) {
                            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.gijoe);
                        } else if (i == 2) {
                            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.reportpiracy);
                        } else if (i == 3) {
                            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.svsc1);
                        }

                        i++;
                        Log.e("", "image Updated");
                        if (i == 3) {
                            i = 0;
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, 0, 5000);

        }

    }

    return layout;
}
```

Comment: http://www.mopri.de/2010/timertask-bad-do-it-the-android-way-use-a-handler/

Answer (score 0):

Best demo for this problem i found here

http://venkoolit.blogspot.in/2013/06/change-images-in-base-adapter.html

Comment: Link only answers are depreciated on this site, try to elaborate more , so that your answer remain valid even if the link dies